# How to execute HTTP request to daemon's *.bin endpoint like http://localhost/getblocks.bin

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, daemon

I am studying the wallet code and I found that it executes `http://localhost/getblocks.bin` request to the monero daemon. However when I try to execute this request in a browser (using GET method) it returns 404. I was just trying to see what the output looks like.

I am able to call all the other endpoints just *.bin gives me trouble.

What is so special about them? How I am supposed to build my HTTP request in order to succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, all of the `.bin` methods are binary methods (as the suffix alludes to). The input and output parameters are binary, serialized objects as defined in [this file](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/rpc/core_rpc_server_commands_defs.h)

These methods are generally for more specialized use cases. In almost all normal use cases, the JSON methods should suffice.

For `getblocks.bin`, there is some documentation [here](https://github.com/el00ruobuob/monero-site/blob/3413322a1aa71ec00b7c828f15dab9cc1bf3fc57/_i18n/en/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.md#get_blocks.bin) which details the input and output parameters.